# How to find nth derivative of $1/(1+x+x^2+x^3)$

Tags: derivatives, partial-fractions

I was trying to solve a differentiation question but unable to understand .

My question is :

find the $n^{th}$ derivative of  $1/(1+x+x^2+x^3)$

I know that if we divide the numerator by denominator then the expression would be :

$1- x(1+ x^2 + x )/(1+x+x^2+x^3)$

But now how to find the nth derivative?

Please somebody explain this..

Thanx :-)

Comment: First you should review how to derivate $1/f(x)$. After that things will be easier. Have you tried to derivate something? Can we see what you have done?

Comment: My first two thoughts are: **(1)** compute its Taylor series (by doing arithmetic with other, known Taylor series), and **(2)** simplify the function (e.g. partial fractions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\frac1{1+x+x^2+x^3}=\frac1{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{x+i}+\frac C{x-i}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3)=1-x^4$, so $$\frac1{1+x+x^2+x^3}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^4}=\frac{1-x}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}=\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}.$$
(After the fact, this factorization is easy to see directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Find the first derrivative and then the second and then the third, you might see a pattern emerge, then write down the general equation that follows that pattern the nth derrivative

Answer (score 1):

My answer is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac1{1+x+x^2+x^3}&=\frac{1}{2 (x+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{2 x}{4 (x^2+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2 (x+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{1}{4}\bigl[\ln\bigl(x^2+1\bigr)\bigr]',\\
\biggl(\frac1{x+1}\biggr)^{(n)}&=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(x+1)^{n+1}},\\
\biggl(\frac1{x^2+1}\biggr)^{(n)}&=\frac{n!}{(2x)^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k}\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}\\
&=(-1)^nn!\frac{\sin[(n+1)\operatorname{arccot}x]}{(1+x^2)^{(n+1)/2}}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}
\begin{vmatrix}
2x & 1+x^2 & 0 & \dotsm&0& 0& 0\\
2 & 4x & 1+x^2 & \dotsm& 0&0& 0\\
0 & 6 & 6x & \dotsm& 0& 0&0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \ddots&\dotsm& \dotsm& \dotsm\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm&2(n-2)x& 1+x^2& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm&(n-2)(n-1)&2(n-1)x & 1+x^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm&0& (n-1)n& 2nx
\end{vmatrix},\\
\bigl[\ln\bigl(x^2+1\bigr)\bigr]^{(n+1)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!} {(x^2+1)^{k}} B_{n+1,k}(2x,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!} {(x^2+1)^{k}} 2^k B_{n+1,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!} {(x^2+1)^{k}} 2^k \frac{1}{2^{n-k+1}}\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k+1}x^{2k-n-1}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)!}{(2x)^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}} {(x^2+1)^{k}} \frac{1}{k}\binom{k}{n-k+1}(2x)^{2k-1}.
\end{align*}

References

1. [Show that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right] = \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\sin[(n+1)\arctan x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1786053)
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418636
3. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
4. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
5. Feng Qi, *Determinantal expressions and recursive relations of Delannoy polynomials and generalized Fibonacci polynomials*, Journal of Nonlinear and Convex Analysis **22** (2021), no. 7, 1225--1239.